# Django. Как создать два внешних ключа в модели Товара- для названия каталога и его слага

Tags: django

возникла проблема с созданием и работой внешних ключей. Код models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(Q(status='в наличии') | Q(status='под заказ') | Q(status='нет в наличии'))

class Goods(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('ожидается', 'Ожидается'),
        ('в наличии', 'В наличии'),
        ('под заказ', 'Под заказ'),
        ('нет в наличии', 'Нет в наличии'),
    )
    goods_name = models.CharField(max_length = 70, verbose_name='Имя товара')
    goods_info = models.TextField(blank = True, verbose_name='Описание товара') 
    manufacturer = models.TextField(blank = True, verbose_name='Производитель товара') 
    product_care = models.TextField(blank = True, verbose_name='Уход') 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='eco_goods', verbose_name = 'Администратор')
    goods_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/goods/%Y/%m', verbose_name = 'Изображение товара')
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length = 15, verbose_name='Код товара')
    price = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True, verbose_name='Цена')
    exposed = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name= 'Выставлен')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name= 'Создан')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name= 'Обновлен')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='ожидается', verbose_name = 'Статус')
    category_name = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null = True, verbose_name = 'Каталог', related_name = 'category_name')
    category_slug = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null = True, verbose_name = 'Слаг каталога', related_name = 'category_slug')
    goods_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique = True, verbose_name = 'Слаг товара')
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товары'
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        ordering = ('-exposed',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.goods_name

    def info_as_list(self):
        return self.goods_info.split('\n')

    def less_goods_info(self):
        return u"%s..." % (self.goods_info[:150],)


class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length = 70, verbose_name='Каталог')
    category_info = models.TextField(blank = True, verbose_name='Информация о каталоге') 
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/categories', verbose_name = 'Изображение категории')
    category_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique = True, verbose_name = 'Слаг каталога')
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Каталоги"
        verbose_name = "Каталог"
        ordering = ('category_name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

Т.к. везде, где фигурируют товары, нужно использовать не только название каталога, но и его слаг, то приходится делать дополнительный запрос к бд. Чтобы решить эту проблему, подумывала сделать 2 ключа к Товарам - имя каталога и его слаг. Для этого нужно использовать related_name, но такой код

```
category_name = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null = True, verbose_name = 'Каталог', related_name = 'category_name')
category_slug = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null = True, verbose_name = 'Слаг каталога', related_name = 'category_slug')
```

не работает. Работает кое-как, если в related_name указать немного измененное имя поля (я добавила f в начале), что-то вроде

```
category_name = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null = True, verbose_name = 'Каталог', related_name = 'fcategory_name')
category_slug = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null = True, verbose_name = 'Слаг каталога', related_name = 'fcategory_slug')
```

А это ошибка, при создании  миграций

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
ecoshop.Goods.category_name: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'Goods.category_name' clashes with field name 'Category.category_name'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Category.category_name', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Goods.category_name'.
ecoshop.Goods.category_name: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Goods.category_name' clashes with field name 'Category.category_name'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Category.category_name', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Goods.category_name'.
ecoshop.Goods.category_slug: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'Goods.category_slug' clashes with field name 'Category.category_slug'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Category.category_slug', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Goods.category_slug'.
ecoshop.Goods.category_slug: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Goods.category_slug' clashes with field name 'Category.category_slug'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Category.category_slug', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Goods.category_slug'.
```

Как уже сказала, с добавлением f оно заработало. Но при создании товара в админ панели возникает проблема. Когда я выбираю для товара каталог (допустим, растения), то поле слага каталога показывает не слаг растения, а список всех каталогов.
Скажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать 2 ключа к товарам (каталог и его слаг), чтобы в админке не выбирать еще и слаг для товара (ведь в модели каталога он автоматически создается). То есть выбрать каталог товара, а слаг автоматически выбирается этого каталога.

К сожалению, информации по этому вопросу толком не нашла. Вопрос банальный, но поможет любой совет. Спасибо заранее.

[image: Так выглядит в админке]

(Вот так в админке выглядит, не знаю уже что с этим делать *(:3 」∠)* )

Comment: Слаг каталога в сущности товара не нужен. Если он нужен где-то на "морде" то его  вполне можно подтянуть из сущности каталога через объектную модель. Поэтому лишний запрос в БД тоже не нужен.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что можно использовать что-то по типу goods = Goods.published.get(goods_name = "Протея"),  goods.category_name.category_slug ?

Comment: Вам нужно скорректировать объектную модель для начала. Тащить в одну сущность поля из другой сущности плохая практика. А, главное, ничего кроме лишних трудозатрат это не даст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам для какой-то цели нужно использовать слаг каталога применительно к товару, то не нужно создавать дополнительные внешние ключи и делать дополнительные запросы к БД.

Всё можно получить из объектной модели.

Пример:

```
goods_item = Goods.objects.get(pk=1)
goods_slug = goods_item.category.slug
```

Соответственно в модели сущности товара надо исправить

```
category_name = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null = True, verbose_name = 'Каталог', related_name = 'category_name')
    category_slug = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null = True, verbose_name = 'Слаг каталога', related_name = 'category_slug')
    goods_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique = True, verbose_name = 'Слаг товара')
```

на приблизительно следующее:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```